# How to UPDATE value for fields inside a xml column : SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration

I have a sql table let's say Criteria, having a xml column ResultCriteria.

Criteria

```
       CriteriaID   CriteriaName   ResultCriteria
       1            Criteria1      <Results>.... </Results>
```

Value for ResultCriteriaColumn :

```
<Results>
 <Result Name=Result1 Title=SearchResultTile1 SortOrder=Asc>
 <Result Name=Result2 Title=SearchResultTile2>
 <Result Name=Result3 Title=SearchResultTile3 Parent=XYZ>
</Results>
```

And a configuration table where Titles for Result columns are stored like:-

```
  ResultColumnNameID  ResultColumnName     Title
  1                   Result1              TitleA
  2                   Result2              TitleB
```

Now i have to update(Change name from a config table) ResultCriteria for every row through a sql script.

I have managed to fetch data in two table variable like

1. ResultLookup

   ```
      ResultColumnName  Title
      Result1           Title1
      Result2           Ttile3
   ```
2. TempTableToUpdate (i created this for first row, so that i can repeat this logic on every row by using cursor.)

   ```
      CriteriaRow1    ResultXML
      Criteria1       <Name='Result1' Title='Result1Title' Parent='ABC'/>
      Criteria1       <Name='Result2' Title='Result2Title' Sort='ASC'/>
      Criteria1       <Name='Result3' Title='Result3Title' Parent='XYZ'/>
   ```

PS: ResultColumnName is unique

Now i just have to replace Title from ResultLookup(Table 1) to ResultXML, convert everything back to Xml. Finally update this new xml into row 1 of Criteria table.

Could someone please suggest how this can be achieved in SQL Server 2012 ?